# Using regex_replace with smarty to remove product names

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, smarty

I'm using an editor driven by Smarty template engine.

I have data that is passed into $productName via an API that produces a string which looks like this:

Hills Portable 170 Clothesline,Versaline Broadline Clothesline,Austral Addaline 35 Clothesline,Hills Rotary 8 Clothesline

What I need is to only show **the first** product from this string that is from the Hills Brand (Brands above are Hills, Versaline, Austral).

The template syntax allows two parameters to be passed in after the command regex_replace:

The first is the **regular expression to be replaced** and the second is the string of **text to replace it with**.

Here's the code:

```
{$productName|regex_replace:" ":" "}
```

What I need help with is **specifying the actual regular expression** so that anything in between "Hills" and the comma that separates it from the next product name remains, and everything else is removed.

**Current output:**
Hills Portable 170 Clothesline,Versaline Broadline Clothesline,Austral Addaline 35 Clothesline,Hills Rotary 8 Clothesline

**Desired output:**
Hills Portable 170 Clothesline

Here's the documentation on regex_replace from Smarty: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be complicated, but in this case it's fairly simply.

```
{$productName|regex_replace:"/,.+/":""}
```

This expression captures a comma, followed by anything else and replaces it with nothing.

Comment: OK this could work. Say I wanted to capture everything from the second comma onwards, or third comma onwards. How would that look? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey, I'm actually not very good with RegEx honestly I'll give it a try, but I can't promise anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can 
1) split the string first and put into array

var str = "How are , doing today?";
var res = str.split(",");

res is a array and just pick the desired index